# Error Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar

Tags: java, android-studio, material, theme, actionbar

No se por que me da error en de values/Themes

**Error**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**theme.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.APPadventureTravel" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. ->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="letrasRojas" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**themes.xml (Nigth)**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.APPadventureTravel" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He solucionado el error agregando la siguiente línea al archivo build.gradle en la aplicación:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```